# Pygame window wont move or close after using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

I have had this problem for ages now with many different projects now, so I really want to find out how to fix it. For example, in one of my projects, I created a level editor for a game. The level editor had the option to save and load different levels from a file using `tkinter.filedialog`.

Now after I select the file, the game will still work, but the 'X' close button doesn't work anymore, and I can't move the window.

The game itself works as usual, and I can still interact with everything inside of the window, but I can't move or close the window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Literally after a google search, i dont think anyone has had this issue, maybe its a silly mistake in your code. Did you say `root.mainloop()` anywhere? im pretty sure you mustve used `root.withdraw()` to hide the window

Comment: I wrote `root.withdraw()` before `pygame.init()` but no `root.mainloop()` here...

Comment: try adding a `root.mainloop()` when you are done wid `filedialog`

Comment: Ok. I will try this now.

Comment: Nope :( Can't move the window or close it or use the game now.

Comment: If it helps, I am running windows 10 and using python 3.7.6 with pygame 1.9.6

Comment: im not sure as to why this weird behaviour, maybe the way pygame window is being confused with tkinter, not sure as to wats hapng tho

Comment: Can I give a link to a python file with the minimal reproducible example on google drive?

Comment: you can actually attach it wid the Q

Comment: I will do that.

Comment: Ok. While I was making the example, I found that the wierd stuff only occurred when you call tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename in A DIFFERENT SCRIPT from the main script. Weird... I am trying to figure this out now.

Comment: you actually never told that in the question, mayb use it in the same module itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I figured this one out. The problem went away when I called the tkinter functions from a key press, not a mouse press.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings with SO, you can accept this as the answer tomorrow. Happy Coding :D