# How to activate pygame screen after using tkinter directory browser?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

It seems I have similar problem like Daniel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356374/pygame-window-wont-move-or-close-after-using-tkinter) but couldn't find solution.

In pygame I'm calling tkinter directory browser to allow user to choose folder he'll work with in further part of program. Unfortunately pygame window loose focus for directory browser and I'm unable to get it back automatically - user have to click on pygame window to focus on it again.

The problem is that if he click on button to choose folder again (ex. if choosed wrong one and want to change) first click activates window and then second click run button.

So it feel like first click was not working.. Specially because hovers works even window is not active.

So far I used root.quit() to get rid of tkinter window but it doesn't change anything.

```
    path = askdirectory(title='Select Folder', initialdir=default_path)
    self.tk_root.quit()
```

Is there any way to get this window active?

Comment: maybe use some GUI module specially for PyGame instead of `tkinter`. As for me using PyGame with any GUI - `tkinter`, `PyQt`, `wxPython`, etc. - is very wierd combination. See PyGame documentation: [GUI](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui)

Comment: @furas I've checked it already but couldn't find directory browser in any of them. Do you know which one might help?

Comment: you have to create own directory browser using widgets and `os.listdir()`

Comment: in [PGU](https://www.pygame.org/project/108) I see image with directory browser.

Comment: i checked also source code on GitHub and I found FileDialog in [examples gui12.py](https://github.com/parogers/pgu/blob/master/examples/gui12.py). In source code I see also [FileDialog](https://github.com/parogers/pgu/blob/master/pgu/gui/dialog.py#L64)

Comment: in [ocempGUI examples](http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/guiwidget.html) I see also image with widgets [FileList and FileDialog](http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/img/filelist_dialog.png)

Comment: in [pygame_gui](https://github.com/MyreMylar/pygame_gui) I see in source code [FileDialog](https://github.com/MyreMylar/pygame_gui/blob/main/pygame_gui/windows/ui_file_dialog.py)

Comment: you could use them to create widget to select folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use some `PyGame GUI` module for this - ie. `PGU`, `OcempGU`, `SGC` or new `pygame_gui`

More on `PyGame.org` with tag: [GUI](https://www.pygame.org/tags/gui)

---

### PGU

[PGU](https://github.com/parogers/pgu) has some [File Browser](https://www.pygame.org/project/108)

[image]

Source code: [pgu.gui.dialog.FileDialog](https://github.com/parogers/pgu/blob/master/pgu/gui/dialog.py#L64)

Examples: [examples/gui12.py](https://github.com/parogers/pgu/blob/master/examples/gui12.py)

---

### OcempGUI

[OcempGUI](http://ocemp.sourceforge.net) has some `FileList` and `FileDialog` in [examples](http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/guiwidget.html)

[image]

---

### pygame_gui

[pygame_gui](https://github.com/MyreMylar/pygame_gui) has some `UIFileDialog`

Doc: [UIFileDialog](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pygame_gui.windows.html#module-pygame_gui.windows.ui_file_dialog)

Source code: [UIFileDialog](https://github.com/MyreMylar/pygame_gui/blob/main/pygame_gui/windows/ui_file_dialog.py)

Examples: [pygame_gui_examples](https://github.com/MyreMylar/pygame_gui_examples) and [file_dialog_test.py](https://github.com/MyreMylar/pygame_gui_examples/blob/master/file_dialog_test.py)

---

### Minimal working code in `pygame_gui`

Its uses standard `FileDialog` with `allow_picking_directories=True` to select directory.

But it also displays filenames which you can select. In next example I will remove filenames.

```
import pygame
import pygame_gui

# --- constants ---

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# --- classes ---

# ... empty ...

# --- functions ---

def open_file_dialog():
    global file_dialog

    # center dialog
    rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (200, 50))
    rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
    
    # create dialog
    file_dialog = pygame_gui.windows.ui_file_dialog.UIFileDialog(rect=rect, manager=manager, allow_picking_directories=True)
    
# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# - objects -

# center button
rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (200, 50))
rect.center = screen.get_rect().center

# create button
button_directory = pygame_gui.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=rect, text='Select Directory', manager=manager)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    time_delta = clock.tick(30)/1000.0

    # - events -
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:

            # handle button's events
            if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
                if event.ui_element == button_directory:
                    open_file_dialog()
                    
            # handle dialog's events
            if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_FILE_DIALOG_PATH_PICKED:        
                if event.ui_element == file_dialog:
                    print('Selected:', event.text)
                
        manager.process_events(event)

    # - updates -
    
    manager.update(time_delta)

    # - draws -
    
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    manager.draw_ui(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

In this version I used `FileDialog` to create own class which always uses `allow_picking_directories=True` and it removes files from list.

```
import pygame
import pygame_gui

# --- constants ---

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# --- classes ---

class DirectoryDialog(pygame_gui.windows.ui_file_dialog.UIFileDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # always select folders
        self.allow_picking_directories = True
        
    def update_current_file_list(self):
        super().update_current_file_list()

        # keep only folders
        self.current_file_list = [item for item in self.current_file_list if item[1] == '#directory_list_item']
            
# --- functions ---

def open_file_dialog():
    global file_dialog

    # center dialog
    rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (200, 50))
    rect.center = screen.get_rect().center

    # create dialog        
    file_dialog = DirectoryDialog(rect=rect, manager=manager)
    
# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# - objects -

# center button
rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (200, 50))
rect.center = screen.get_rect().center

# create button
button_directory = pygame_gui.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=rect, text='Select Directory', manager=manager)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    time_delta = clock.tick(30)/1000.0

    # - events -
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:

            # handle button's events
            if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
                if event.ui_element == button_directory:
                    open_file_dialog()
                    
            # handle dialog's events
            if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_FILE_DIALOG_PATH_PICKED:        
                if event.ui_element == file_dialog:
                    print('Selected:', event.text)
                
        manager.process_events(event)

    # - updates -
    
    manager.update(time_delta)

    # - draws -
    
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    manager.draw_ui(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

After clicking button

[image]

Dialog can be moved and resized

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Author didn't expect that someone will need `dialog` which is `not movable` and `not resizable`.

But digging in source code I found `dialog` is based on `UIWindow` which has option `resizable` and you can use it in own class

```
 self.resizable = False
```

But it still can move. But UIWindow has also `title_bar` and when I set it `None` then it can't move window (but it still display `title bar` - I expected it will remove it)

```
class DirectoryDialog(pygame_gui.windows.ui_file_dialog.UIFileDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # always allow for picking folders
        self.allow_picking_directories = True
        
        #self.enable_title_bar = False  # didn't work
        
        self.title_bar = None
        self.resizable = False
         
    def update_current_file_list(self):
        super().update_current_file_list()
        
        # keep only folders
        self.current_file_list = [item for item in self.current_file_list if item[1] == '#directory_list_item']
```

or you can change it after creating dialog

```
# create dialog
#file_dialog = pygame_gui.windows.ui_file_dialog.UIFileDialog(rect=rect, manager=manager, allow_picking_directories=True)
file_dialog = DirectoryDialog(rect=rect, manager=manager, window_title='Select Directory 2')
file_dialog.resizable = False
file_dialog.title_bar = None
```

---

**EDIT**

Using file `'theme.json'` with theme I could create something like this.

[image]

[image]

I used different colors for different elements to better recognize which settting changes element.

[Documentation](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/theme_guide.html) uses hex values but luckly it can use also color names predefined in PyGame:

```
import pygame

for item in pygame.color.THECOLORS.items(): 
    print(item)
```

I didn't try to change fonts because it seems it need to add files `.ttf` and set it in theme. I didn't find example/code which uses font installed in system.

---

Code:

```
manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), 'theme.json')
```

`theme.json`

```
{
    "defaults":
    {
        "colours":
        {
             "normal_bg": "red",
             "normal_text": "white",
             "normal_border": "blue",

             "hovered_bg": "green",
             "hovered_text": "black",
             "hovered_border": "gold",

             "disabled_bg": "black",
             "disabled_text": "grey",
             "disabled_border": "grey",

             "selected_bg": "green",
             "selected_text": "red",
             "selected_border": "grey4",

             "active_bg": "red",
             "active_text": "white",
             "active_border": "black",

             "dark_bg": "pink"
        }
    },

    "button":
    {
        "misc":
        {
            "shape": "rounded_rectangle",
            "shape_corner_radius": "10",
            "border_width": "3"
        }
    },
    
    "#file_dialog.#file_path_text_line":
    {
        "colours":
        {
            "normal_border": "green",

            "dark_bg": "orange"
        },
        
        "misc":
        {
            "shape": "rounded_rectangle",
            "shape_corner_radius": "10",
            "border_width": "3"
        }
    },
    
    "#file_dialog.#file_display_list":
    {
        "colours":
        {
            "dark_bg": "yellow"
        },
        
        "misc":
        {
            "shape": "rounded_rectangle",
            "shape_corner_radius": "10",
            "border_width": "3"
        }  
    },
    
    "#file_dialog.#file_display_list.#file_list_item":
    {
        "colours":
        {
            "normal_bg": "blue"
        }  
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example with rounded buttons and bigger font (default `fira_code`)

[image]

`theme.json`

```
{
    "defaults":
    {
        "colours":
        {
             "normal_bg": "red",
             "normal_text": "white",
             "normal_border": "blue",

             "hovered_bg": "green",
             "hovered_text": "black",
             "hovered_border": "gold",

             "disabled_bg": "black",
             "disabled_text": "grey",
             "disabled_border": "grey",

             "selected_bg": "green",
             "selected_text": "red",
             "selected_border": "grey4",

             "active_bg": "red",
             "active_text": "white",
             "active_border": "black",

             "dark_bg": "pink"
        }
    },

    "button":
    {
        "misc":
        {
            "shape": "rounded_rectangle",
            "shape_corner_radius": "10",
            "border_width": "3"
        },
        
        "font":
        {
            "name": "fira_code",
            "size": "24"
        }             
    },

    "#file_dialog.#close_button":
    {
        "misc":
        {
            "shape": "rounded_rectangle",
            "shape_corner_radius": "10",
            "border_width": "3"
        },
        
        "font":
        {
            "name": "fira_code",
            "size": "24"
        }             
    },

    "#file_dialog.#title_bar":
    {
        "misc":
        {
            "shape": "rounded_rectangle",
            "shape_corner_radius": "10",
            "border_width": "3"
        },
        
        "font":
        {
            "name": "fira_code",
            "size": "24"
        }             
    },
    
    "#file_dialog.#file_path_text_line":
    {
        "colours":
        {
            "normal_border": "green",

            "dark_bg": "orange"
        },
        
        "misc":
        {
            "shape": "rounded_rectangle",
            "shape_corner_radius": "10",
            "border_width": "3"
        },
        
        "font":
        {
            "name": "fira_code",
            "size": "24"
        }  
    },
    
    "#file_dialog.#file_display_list":
    {
        "colours":
        {
            "dark_bg": "yellow"
        },
        
        "misc":
        {
            "shape": "rounded_rectangle",
            "shape_corner_radius": "10",
            "border_width": "3"
        }  
    },
    
    "#file_dialog.#file_display_list.#file_list_item":
    {
        "colours":
        {
            "normal_bg": "blue"
        }  
    }
}
```

---

**Finish:**

I put all my code and screenshots on GitHub: github.com/furas/pygame-pygame_gui-examples

Comment: It works great! 
But now I have couple more problems - actually with styling. I've went through documentation but haven't find answer for follwing:
- how to disable filedialog from dragging? (i wan't to set it to fill whole game screen and stay still, but now it can be moved around)
- how to change backgrounds and fonts? (i can set image for file dialog itself and bg color for path box but for other widgets it seems to not work same way :x )

Comment: I never used `pygame_gui` before. I dig in source code and I found dialog is based on `UIWindow` which has option `resizable`. And when I change option `title_bar` then it stop moving it. See new code in answer. I don't know how to change background and font - it would need to check it in source code. Probably in `__init__` it would have to access directly all elements in `dialog`. OR maybe it would need [theming](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/theme_reference/theme_file_dialog.html)

Comment: I added example with theme. I changed only colors and shaped but I didn't try to change font - probably it needs to add files `.tff` and set it in theme file.

Comment: For fonts we can use pygame.font.Sysfont("font_name", size) but it has to be assigned to each part of file dialog separately. Probably it's better to do it via "theme.json" if possible.

I've managed to style everything I needed excpeting close button https://pasteboard.co/JMdoMH3.png 

in __Init__ i have found all other buttons but not this one..

Comment: `pygame_gui` preferes `them.json` and I don't see special method to do it directly - I only found name of default font `fira_code` - check `manager.get_theme().get_font_dictionary().default_font_name` - which I could use in `theme.json` to change font size. But to use other font it needs full path to font file in `theme.json` to load it.

Comment: rouded close button needs simply `"#file_dialog.#close_button"`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't worked. Now I've checked "default_theme.json" and there is "window.#close_button" which is used for that 
Now I'm fighting with fonts basing on "pygame_gui/core/ui_font_dictionary.py", we'll see how it works

Comment: strange, `"#file_dialog.#close_button"` works for me. Sometimes problem makes event single comma in `json` file. File has to be perfectly formatted - without `,` after last elements, names always with `" "`, not `' '`, etc.

Comment: I put my last `theme.json` with screenshot. I think it is time to finish this answer because main problem was resolved. I put all my code and screenshots on GitHub: https://github.com/furas/pygame-pygame_gui-examples

Answer (score 0):

Before you close the window you have to iconify it.

```
root.iconify()
root.destroy()
```

When you first iconify the window, tkinter give the control again to the pygame window, then you can destroy the tkinter window and the pygame window keep active. :)